# What does test="element[@attribute]" do in XSLT?

Tags: xslt, xpath

What does this do exactly?

```
<xsl:if test="./employee/first-name[@id='14']" >
```

I mean, when will this case be true, if `./employee/first-name[@id]` != `null` or `""`, or what?

### Edit

I have edited the statement above, so it tests if element first-name with id=14 have a body or its body contains a data or return true if first-name event don't have a body?

Comment: there is a nice online tool for evaluating XPath expressions here: http://b-cage.net/code/web/xpath-evaluator.html Put in some XML and try your expression.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If the query in `<xsl:if test=...>` returns at least one *node* then the conditional evaulates to true.

The new XSLT expression you gave:

```
<xsl:if test="./employee/first-name[@id='14']" >
```

will evaluate to *true* if and only if there exists a `first-name` node under `employee` whose `id` attribute is equal to the string `'14'`

```
<employee><first-name id="" /></employee>     <!-- does NOT match -->
<employee><first-name id="014" /></employee>  <!-- does NOT match -->
<employee>
  <first-name id="foobar" />
  <first-name id="14" />                      <!-- DOES match -->
</employee>
```

Comment: Could you please re-answer the modified question above ?

Answer (score 3):

Seems there's some missing pieces, as last `or ""` will throw an error. But, let's see:

```
    ./                    search within current node
    employee/first-name   for an employee tag with an first-name child tag
    [@id]                 where first-name tag have an id attribute
    !=null                and that first-name tag have some value
```

Answer (score 2):

`<xsl:if>` tests an expression (like the `if` in traditional languages). The result of the expression is evaluated as a Boolean.

In your case, the expression is an XPath selector (`/employee/first-name[@id]`) - it will always return a node-set. Node-sets are evaluated as `false` only when they are empty (e.g. no matching nodes found).

The expression could also be something like `number(/employee/id)`. Now the expression result is a number, which is evaluated as `false` if it is zero or `NaN`, `true` in all other cases.

Other values that are `false` are the empty string `''` (`true` in all other cases) and the result of `false()` itself. Note that there also is a `true()` function to return a Boolean `true`.

Also note that the string `'false'` evaluates to `true`, per the the described rule for strings.